# Incorrect toll total cost while calculating route

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to get the toll cost estimation using here-api, but the toll cost I'm getting in response is different from the actual cost at toll booth. For example, I tried requesting toll cost from Hoboken (LatLng: 40.7439905, -74.0323626) to Newyork (LatLng: 40.7127837, -74.0059413) for Taxi (commercial vehicle) - regular petrol car, using API

`https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json`

with the params

```
"app_id" = MY_APP_ID
"app_code = MY_APP_CODE
"mode" = "fastest;car"
"cost_optimize" = "0"
"waypoint0" = "40.7439905,-74.0323626"
"waypoint1" = "40.7127837,-74.0059413"
"tollVehicleType" = 13
"commercial" = 1
"currency" = "USD"
```

But the *totalCost* I'm receiving in response json is 7.0 USD, where the actual toll charge for Car is  **15.0 USD**.  I have cross checked the route I received in the same response json, and it's correct.

I tried other params mentioned [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/toll-cost/topics/resource-calculateroute-input-interface.html), but didn't get accurate answer. Am I missing any detail in request? Can anyone suggest me the method to achieve the proper result?

Comment: You are using testing environment. cit mean client integration testing. Try to use https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json

Comment: Yes, I'm using cit intentionally. Do you mean, when I'll switch to live environment, I'll get the proper 'toll cost total'?

Comment: I think that this is possible, but I don't know for sure. Also, make sure that you are really set all options. Quite often rules for paid roads might be tricky.

Comment: Please provide the exact link where you think the toll cost is wrong.

Comment: Well the question is too old. So I'm not sure if the result will be same now or not, also I don't know if new version of API is available or not. But a year ago, I tried with the same parameters mentioned in my question and it was returning incorrect amount of Toll 'totalCost'.